# Issue with connecting Golang application on Cloud Run with Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-run

I try to get all Documents from Firestore using the below function.

The credentials are stored in an encrypted file in a GCP Cloud Source repository. 
I decrypted the configuration in the Cloud Build trigger and set the ENV in the Dockerfile pointing to the file. I see the content by RUN ls /app/credentials.json.

The error I get in the application log:
rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"

The credentials are stored in an encrypted file in a GCP Cloud Source repository. 
I decrypted the configuration in the Cloud Build trigger and set the ENV in the Dockerfile pointing to the file. I see the content by RUN ls /app/credentials.json.

The error I get in the application log:
`rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"`

Comment: Could you please provide more details? I don't think you've specified what function you're using, for example. We can't help you if you don't give use useful info.

Answer (score 10):

This error is the result of an HTTPS failure where the certificate cannot be verified. The [Alpine base image](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine) is missing a package that provides root certificates. Currently the [Cloud Run quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy) is missing this for at least the Go language.

Assuming this is your problem, add the following to the final stage of your Dockerfile:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache ca-certificates
```